# MS Access Detect when Refreshing a Linked Table

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

Is there a way to detect when the user presses Refresh All or Refresh in Access? I would like to run a VBA script when the table is refreshed. If there isn't a way, how do I refresh all linked tables using VBA? I only know of refreshing/requerying  forms.

Comment: Will this help? https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/961807-vba-auto-refresh-linked-table-manager-linked-tables

Comment: None that I know of. Links are live connections. Why would you need to 'refresh' table?

Comment: You can hide MS Access tables interface from user, and provide him with own linked table update form with corresponding VBA actions

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no event for handling the tdf.RefreshLink method. You can refresh all table links with code like this:

```
Public Sub Refresh_Linked_Tables()

    Dim mdb As Access.Application

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

        Set mdb = Access.Application
        Set db = mdb.CurrentDb

        For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
            If LCase(Left(tdf.Name, 4)) <> "msys" Then
                If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
                    tdf.RefreshLink
                End If
            End If
        Next tdf

End Sub
```